# Combining individual MATLAB plots into one figure: is modifying the script the best option?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure, subplot

The script below produces seven individual figures (each includes two plots). I would like to combine them into one big figure which would include all 14 plots. I think two solutions could be possible: either modifying the current script or adding the plots into one after they were already drawn. I am very much a beginner; any simple solution would be very much appreciated.
(My data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ggdh03lo10w85vv/Block-1.mat?dl=0 ).

```matlab
%% loop through frequencies, plot both channels next to each other
% desired # of points
nPoints = 200;

%vary this value to determine how closely you want the plots to be stacked on one another
stackvar = 0.00003;

% loop through frequencies
for f = 1:nf

   % get channel 1 and 2 data for all attenuations (levels)
   % and desired frequency converted

   % from cell to matrix. time in rows, levels in columns
   datatoplot_ch1 = cell2mat(Ch1D.mean(:, f)');
   datatoplot_ch2 = cell2mat(Ch2D.mean(:, f)');

   % plot in new figure for each frequency
   figure

   % loop through levels for this frequency
   for ii = 1:nl

      % plot fresh trace in first plot

      if ii == 1
         % ch 1
         subplot(1, 2, 1)
         plot(datatoplot_ch1(1:nPoints, ii) + stackvar*(nl - (ii - 1)), 'b');

         % ch 2
         subplot(1, 2, 2)
         plot(datatoplot_ch2(1:nPoints, ii) + stackvar*(nl - (ii - 1)), 'r');
      else

         % channel 1
         subplot(1, 2, 1)
         hold on
         plot(datatoplot_ch1(1:nPoints, ii) + stackvar*(nl - (ii - 1)), 'b');
         hold off

         % channel 2
         subplot(1, 2, 2)
         hold on
         plot(datatoplot_ch2(1:nPoints, ii) + stackvar*(nl - (ii - 1)), 'r');
         hold off
      end

      % add level label to identify trace
      subplot(1, 2, 1)
      text(1, stackvar*(nl - (ii - 1)), sprintf('%d', attens(ii)));
      subplot(1, 2, 2)
      text(1, stackvar*(nl - (ii - 1)), sprintf('%d', attens(ii)));
   end

   subplot(1, 2, 1)
   title(sprintf('%s Ch1 %d', BLOCK, freqs(f)));
   subplot(1, 2, 2)
   title(sprintf('%s Ch2 %d', BLOCK, freqs(f)));

end
```

Comment: What do you mean with combining into one figure? Do you want to add each of the plots to the same two axes, or do you want to have a grid of 7x2 axes containing all the plots?

Comment: I would like to have a final big figure with 14 plots in it (so yes, 7x2 axes). Thank you for asking; I can see now that my question should be more clearly written.

Comment: Yes, you need to modify the code. `subplot(n, 2, 7)` will draw to the `n`th plot in a 2x7 array of plots. Computing `n` in your loop is quite simple, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily "merge" the plots into one figure after you have already plotted them. What you can do is place the command

```
hold on
```

right after the function `figure` and

```
hold off
```

after the last `title`. This will make sure that the plots are all drawn on the current active figure.

See MATLAB documentation for more details on the function `hold`:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html

Comment: This unfortunately did not help! The output is still the same: 7 different figures (each includes 2 subplots). I also tried to insert `hold on`, `hold off` (in the suggested locations) and I changed `figure` to `figure (1)`. In that case the output is one figure with 2 subplots. But the second subplot contains all the traces on top of each other... What I really need to achieve is one large figure with all 7  
 plots in it (so in total 14 plots).